# Flask IIS wfastcgi Logging from multiple modules

Tags: python, iis, logging, flask, wfastcgi

My Flask App has a structure like below

```
- util/
-- util.py
- module/
-- mod1.py
-- mod2.py
- restserver.py
```

restserver.py has `logging.config.dictConfig` as per https://gist.github.com/jakubczaplicki/c9077a482c2b195b7f3bcbee19dde441

This app is hosted through IIS, with the wfastcgi gateway.
So it only looks for `restserver.app` module and doesn't bother about the `__main__`.

I can see logs from my internal modules using this dict, but the logs from my `restserver.py` routes are not appearing.

I am logging using `app.logger.info()` etc.

Where should the `logging.config.dictConfig` be initalized?
Before `app = Flask(__name__)` or after it?

Do I need a separate logger in `__main__` if I already declared it via the `dictConfig`. I am looking for `TimedRotatingFileHandler`

All my return values and data I get back from `IIS + Flask` is correct,just that my logging is not properly set up and would really like to make it work.